# The usage of such and so

Tags: such

> First question:
> Yesterday it was . . . terrible weather that there were hardly any people out in the streets.
>
> A) so
> B) too
> C) such
> D) such a

In my opinion, it should be D but the answer's A. Nevertheless, my teacher says it is not a good answer! Please help, am I right or not?

Comment: The correct answer is (c) "such" not "so" or "such a". You would use "so" in "yesterday the weather was so terrible that ..."

Comment: Yeah, the answer should be (c)

Comment: '*so...(adjective)...that... (consequence)'*, or '*such...(uncountable noun)...that... (consequence)'*, or, '*such a...(countable noun)...that... (consequence)'*. 'Weather' (in this context) is uncountable so (c).

Comment: @Martin Smith and BladorthinTheGrey and Dan The right answer we are told is A. Can you imagine what it would be like to be studying our language in so a class?